# Working for a US firm from India: How much tax do I need to pay to India and how often?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india

With reference to this question [Tax consequences of working for US company from India](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/45801/tax-consequences-of-working-for-us-company-from-india)

My situation is some what similar to the above one how ever I will describe it in detail,

I am working for a US firm from India. The firm is registered as LLC in USA. It does not have an office in India. I am citizen of India working from home, the salary is directly credited to my account in India.

My Questions

1. Can anybody describe how much tax must must be paid(In India) in such a situation ?
2. When should the taxes be paid(In India) ? i.e Monthly,quarterly or yearly ?

Comment: Are you asking about taxes paid to India or the US?

Answer (score 1):

> Can any body describe how much tax must must be paid(In India) in such a situation ?

As per the tax rates

> When should the taxes be paid(In India) ? i.e Monthly,quarterly or yearly ?

Ideally monthly, Quarterly is also fine, it should be before 15th of the quarter.

If taxes are more than rs10000, 30% should be paid by 15-sep, 60% by 15-dec, 100% by 15-mar. If not paid, penalty at 1% per month on tax due needs to be paid

Comment: How about yearly ?

Comment: @taxes are to be paid in advance by 15th of every quarter. If TDS, then it has to be monthly.

Comment: I did not pay, what will happen ? Please let me know will I be stuck in legal issues.